# Formal definition of 'pure straining flow' and 'pure rotational flow'?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition, flow, vortex

In fluid mechanics the terms '[pure straining flow](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=pure+straining+flow)' and '[pure rotational flow](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=pure+rotational+flow)' are often thrown around (see e.g. here). I have tried looking for a formal definition of these two but have not been able to find one (or in fact anything you might call a definition). So how can we formally define these two terms?

Answer (score 1):

Pure rotational flow is a rigid body rotation.  In pure straining flow, the vorticity tensor is zero.